# Is there a limit in dimension?

Tags: spacetime-dimensions, thought-experiment

According to wikipedia  Dimension

> In physics and mathematics, the dimension of a mathematical space (or
>   object) is informally defined as the minimum number of coordinates
>   needed to specify any point within it.

I want to know whether their is any limit in dimension at infinity. As human being's we can only perceive three dimensions that is length, breadth and height.

Lets say there are two human brothers with their own super powers. One brother we can call him Mr.Big have the power to grow at infinity  and the other Mr.Small with power to shrink infinitesimally  smaller. At starting both brothers are in our dimension so both perceive 3 dimensions. The questions are

1. What dimension(s) Mr.Big perceive while growing? whether he sees higher dimensions as he grows(3,4,5,6 D etc)?
2. What dimension(s) Mr.Small perceive while shrinking? whether he sees lower dimensions as he shrinks and then reach negative dimensions(eg 3,2,1,0,-1 D etc)?
3. Or both see a limit in dimension after growing/shrinking at a particular scale.

Disclamir: Not a Physicist or Mathematician

Comment: In all current physical theories the number of dimensions is independent of scale and it is three. Having said that, there is great interest in models in which this is not the case. It would be "nice" for mathematical reasons, to have more than three dimensions at small distances. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_extra_dimension for such a model that was quite popular some fifteen years ago. In the meantime the buzz has died down because there is no observational evidence for it.

Comment: This question (v1) seems partly spurred by a conflation of the mathematical definition of [dimension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension), and the common use of the word to mean size/length of an object.